# Find element between two span in selenium

Tags: css, selenium

I want to find text between this html using selenium

```
<span class="value">
Receiver 1
<br>
</span>
```

How can make it maybe something like this  `span[class=value]`?

Comment: Try `CSS` selector `"span.value"` or `XPath` `"//span[@class='value']"`. Note that it's just a single `span` element, but not two `span` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do that -

**By CSS Selector:**

```
String data = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.value")).getText();
System.out.println(data);
```

**Using Xpath:**

```
String data = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class,'value']")).getText();
System.out.println(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify the element and use get text. Below line may help you.

```
String data = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='value']")).getText();
System.out.println(data);
```

Thanks.